# Numerical differences between older Mac Mini and newer Macbook

Tags: macos, clang, osx-yosemite, floating-accuracy, accelerate-framework

I have a project that I compile on both my Mac Mini (Core2 Duo) and a 2014 Macbook quadcore i7.  Both are running the latest version of Yosemite.  The application is single threaded and I am compiling the tool and libraries using the exact same version of cmake and the clang (xcode) compiler.  I am getting test failures due to slight numeric differences.

I am wondering if the inconsistency is coming from the clang compiler automatically doing processor specific optimizations, (which I did not select in cmake)? Could the difference be between the processors?  Do the frameworks use processor specific optimizations?  I am using the BLAS/Lapack routines the from the Accelerate framework.  They are called from the SuperLU sparse matrix factorization package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should not expect results from BLAS or LAPACK to be bitwise reproducible across machines.  There are a number of factors that implementors tune to get the best performance, all of which result in small differences in rounding:

- your two machines have different numbers of processors, which will result in work being divided differently for threading purposes (even if your application is single threaded, BLAS may use multiple threads internally).
- your two machines handle hyper threading quite differently, which may also cause BLAS to use different numbers of threads.
- the cache and TLB hierarchy is different between your two machines, which means that different block sizes are optimal for data reuse.
- the SIMD vector size on the newer machine is twice as large as that on the older machine, which again will effect how arithmetic is grouped.
- finally, the newer machine supports FMA (and using FMA is necessary to get the best performance on it); this *also* contributes to small differences in rounding.

Any one of these factors would be enough to result in small differences; taken together it should be expected that the results will not be bitwise identical.  And that's OK, so long as both results satisfy the error bounds of the computation.

Making the results identical would require severely limiting the performance on the newer machine, which would result in your shiny expensive hardware going to waste.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Do you know if the Accelerate Framework:
1. Has a means to turn off threading?
2. Is using CPU-specific instructions/optimizations at runtime?

Since this is a test suite, and I need the results to be reproducible.  I have no issues with wasted performance.  I guess I'll just have to state the specific Platform/Architecture that the tests were run on.

Comment: Does anyone know if the clang compiler from Mac OS X automatically does cpu-specific optimizations?

Comment: You can disable threading for the accelerate BLAS and LAPACK by setting the VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS environment variable to 1.  Accelerate does dispatch into cpu-specific implementations at runtime.  Clang will target the architecture that you tell it to target via flags, but that won't effect accelerate, which is a shared library.

Comment: Is there a good document for Accelerate, especially concerning cpu optimizaitons?  The one I found online referencing the threading flags was for an older os.

Comment: @Juan: In general the most up-to-date documentation is found in the headers themselves, though it's somewhat incomplete.

Comment: I was just using the standard Fortran API, so I had no idea that there were headers.  Thanks!

Comment: @Juan: there's not *much* documentation in the BLAS and LAPACK headers because those functions are pretty well documented elsewhere.  The other parts of Accelerate have more information.